# How could I make javascript reorder my div tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say i have 4 divs (with id="div1" "div2" etc)

How could I use Javascript to make it re-order to 2,3,1,4?

Please don't suggust to use anything else... because what i'm trying to do involves Javascript and i'm only a beginner!

Please be detailed when explaining!! Thanks =3

Answer (score 4):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jBzB4/)**

This should be pretty easy to understand:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
    <div id="div4">4</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container'), 
    divs = container.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    tmpdiv = document.createElement('div'),
    order = [2, 1, 3, 4];

for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    tmpdiv.appendChild(  document.getElementById('div' + order[i])  );
}

container.parentNode.replaceChild(tmpdiv, container);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can insert an element before an other by calling the [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/insertbefore) function on the parent element.

For example if you want to insert div2 before div1, you can do this:

```
parent.insertBefore(div2, div1);
```

The following code inserts div1 before div4:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var div4 = document.getElementById('div4');

var parent = div1.parentNode;

parent.insertBefore(div1, div4);
```

After executing the the order of the divs is 2, 3, 1, 4.

Answer (score -1):

- I'm grabbing the DIV with id container, using [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementById)
- Getting the children of that DIV with `.children()`
- using [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML) and building a new string swapping the 1st and 3rd elements
- setting the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) to the string i just built

**HTML**

```
<div id="containter">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var el = document.getElementById('containter'),
    divs = el.children,
    len = divs.length;

// swap 3 and 1
var html = divs[1].outerHTML;
html += divs[2].outerHTML;
html += divs[0].outerHTML;
html += divs[4].outerHTML;

el.innerHTML = html;
```