# Rearrange div order based on id name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below HTML which is displayed via jQuery, it is a list of users - but I am trying to find a way to specify an id name which makes the appropriate my_list div move to the top of the order?

Example:

```
<div class="my_list" id="peter"><label class="name">Peter - <div id="peter_status"></div></label></div>
<div class="my_list" id="sam"><label class="name">Sam - <div id="sam_status"></div></label></div>
<div class="my_list" id="derek"><label class="name">Derek - <div id="derek_status"></div></label></div>
```

Would turn into the following if I was to specify Sam:

```
<div class="my_list" id="sam"><label class="name">Sam - <div id="sam_status"></div></label></div>
<div class="my_list" id="peter"><label class="name">Peter - <div id="peter_status"></div></label></div>
<div class="my_list" id="derek"><label class="name">Derek - <div id="derek_status"></div></label></div>
```

My attempt at creating some code to assist is below:

```
$( '<div class="my_list" id="sam">' ).insertBefore($( ".my_list" ).first());
```

Comment: So just prepend the element with the given id to the top? `$('#sam').parent().prepend($('#sam'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4bLLz6u5/)**.

Note that we need a **container** for your `div`s to sort:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="my_list" id="peter">
        <label class="name">Peter -
            <div id="peter_status"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="my_list" id="sam">
        <label class="name">Sam -
            <div id="sam_status"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="my_list" id="derek">
        <label class="name">Derek -
            <div id="derek_status"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this JS code does the trick by using the `remove()` and `prepend()` `jQuery` methods:

```
var divId = 'sam';
$('button.sort-divs').on('click', function () {
    var divHtml = $('#' + divId).html();
    $('#' + divId).remove();
    $('.container').prepend(divHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some related answers, found by Googling "javascript rearrange div order":

- [Change div order in CSS or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699594/change-div-order-in-css-or-javascript)
- [change order divs with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628627/change-order-divs-with-jquery)
- [How could I make javascript reorder my div tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248286/how-could-i-make-javascript-reorder-my-div-tags)
- [Reordering of Divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558614/reorder-divs)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an actual answer... Why not flag it as duplicate of one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need much of code. Given every element you need to sort has its own id, you can use this code, easy and scalable:

```
var order = ['sam','peter','derek'];
for (var i = 1; i < order.length; i++) {
    $('#'+order[i]).insertAfter('#'+order[i-1]);
}
```

Here you have a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KarmaProd/4agnc9t1/).